# How do I create a class with arrays and then pass values to a program?

Tags: java

I have an assignment for my class that goes like this:
"Write a Payroll class that uses the following arrays as fields:

- employeeID - An array of seven integers to hold employee identification numbers. 
  The array should be initialized with the following numbers:
  5658845 4520125 7895122 8777541 8451277 1302850 7580489
- hours - An array of seven integers to hold the number of hours worked by each employee.
- payRate - An array of seven doubles to hold each employee's hourly pay rate.
- wages - An array of seven doubles to hold each employee's gross wages.

The class should relate the data in each array through the subscripts. 
For example, the number in element 0 of the hours array should be the number of hours worked by the employee 
whose identification number is stored in element 0 of the employeeID array. 
That same employee's pay rate should be stored in element 0 of the payRate array. 
In addition to the appropriate accessor and mutator methods, 
the class should have a method that accepts an employee's identification number 
as an argument and returns the gross pay for that employee.

I'm having trouble passing values from the program I created.  Here is the class:

```
public class moduleArray2
{
   final int NUM_EMPLOYEES = 7;
   int[] employeeID = {5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489};
   int[] hours = new int[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
   double[] payRate = new double[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
   double[] wages = new double[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
   int employee = 0;
   double wage = 0;


   // setHours method
   public void setHours(int[] time)
   {
      time = hours;

   }

   // setPayRate method
   public void setPayRate(double[] pay)
   {
      pay = payRate;

   }

    // setWages method
   public void setWage(int[] time, int[] pay)
   {
      for (int index = 0; index < NUM_EMPLOYEES; index++)
         wages[index] = time[index] * pay[index];

   }

   //getEmployeeID method
   public int getEmployeeID(int index)
   {

      return employee;

   }   

   // getWage method
   public double getWage(int index)
   {


      return wage;

   }

}
```

The program is supposed to display each employee number and ask the user to enter that employee's hours and pay rate. It should then display each employee's identification number and gross wages.  When I run the program, it simply lists everything as a zero value, including the employee ID numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class moduleArrayDemo2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      final int NUM_EMPLOYEES = 7;
      int[] time = new int[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
      double[] pay = new double[NUM_EMPLOYEES];

      // Create new Scanner object
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Create employee object
      moduleArray2[] employee = new moduleArray2[NUM_EMPLOYEES];

      // A loop that creates objects for each element
      for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++)
         employee[i] = new moduleArray2();


      for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter hours for Employee #" + employee[i].getEmployeeID(i) +
                           ": ");
         time[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
         employee[i].setHours(time);

         System.out.print("Enter how much Employee #" + employee[i].getEmployeeID(i) +
                          " makes per hour: ");
         pay[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
         employee[i].setPayRate(pay);

      }

      for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Employee #" + employee[i].getEmployeeID(i) + 
                            " Wages: " + employee[i].getWage(i));

      }    

   }

 }
```

I can do arrays in a simple program, and I can do classes with programs that create instances of those classes.  Arrays in a class...I feel totally lost.  How do I reference the arrays in the class to get values in the program itself?  Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your setters are backwards. You have `time = hours;` which will set the method variable `time` (no longer exists after the execution of the method) to the value of the `hours` field. You want to do the opposite: set the field `hours` to the value of the `time` variable (what you're passing to your method).

Comment: Cool.  I went ahead and switched them, but the program still reads everything as a zero value when the list is created:                for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Employee #" + employee[i].getEmployeeID(i) + 
" Wages: " + employee[i].getWage(i));

      }

Comment: Is your excercise really stated as `Write a Payroll class that uses the following arrays as fields`? Cannot you create an Employee class with ID, hours, payrate and wage fields? I can hardly believe it.

Comment: I know, right?  I was successful in creating that class, but arrays in the class go right over my head.

Comment: Why teachers don't read books about software design? It's obious that what problem needs is to create a Employee class with a employeeID, hour,.. fields. And use a List<Employee> (much better than array in most of cases). Good pratices should be learned from begining.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're messing up accessor methods arguments, their actual values and accessed objects.

```
class ModuleArray2
    int[] employeeID = {5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489};
    int NUM_EMPLOYEES = employeeID.length; // I assume you've got it defined somewhere

    int[] hours = new int[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
    double[] payRate = new double[NUM_EMPLOYEES];
    double[] wages = new double[NUM_EMPLOYEES];

    // setHours method - will reassign the whole array of `hours` with the provided argument `time` ; I'm leaving this method with a signature that you have provided just to have a place to put my comment on it
    public void setHours(int[] time) {
        hours = time;
        // time = hours; // this is wrong - it would assign class field value to the temporary argument variable `time`, and then just throw it away (since `time` in this scope is temporary)
    }

    // setHours method - will set working hours in one of an array `hours` elements specified by the provided index - number of an employee it refers to
    public void setHours(int employeeNumber, int workedHours) {
        hours[employeeNumber] = workedHours;
    }

    // setPayRate method - same as above
    public void setPayRate(int employeeNumber, double payRate) {
        payRates[employeeNumber] = payRate;
    }

    // setWage method - same as above
    public void setWage(int employeeNumber, double wage) {
        wages[employeeNumber] = wage;
    }

    // getWage method - will return the wage for employee given by an index in array number
    public double getWage(int employeeNumber) {
        return wages[employeeNumber];
    }

    //getEmployeeID method - will return an ID of employee given by an index in array number
    public int getEmployeeID(int employeeNumber) {
        return employeeID[employeeNumber];
    }

    //getEmployeeIndexFromID method - will return the index of employee given by his ID number - this is inverse function of the function 'getEmployeeID'
    public int getEmployeeIndexFromID(int employeeID) {
        int index;
        // search implementation goes here
        // you should try to write it on your own
        return index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the Tax program change the total variable to an array that accepts 5 double values from the user then pass it to the tax method to get the tax on the total.